# Activiti 6.0.0 Unable to get the Form properties while completing task

Tags: java, spring-boot, alfresco, activiti, alfresco-enterprise

I am new to Activiti 6.0.0 I have created one process with user task and second user task has two form properties but when I have completed first user task and try to complete second user task then form properties not display and I am unable to complete the user task..

Below the is my bpm process:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef">
  <process id="test-issue-workflow" name="Test Issue Workflow" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="sid-5A259606-C7C4-4A8E-95F0-F2E8B9D0301E"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="task-1" name="User Task 1" activiti:candidateGroups="development">
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-809C5257-C1D3-4B64-8258-8C5B4F5DCD4A" sourceRef="sid-5A259606-C7C4-4A8E-95F0-F2E8B9D0301E" targetRef="start-progress"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="task-2" name="User Task 2" activiti:candidateGroups="qa">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="workRequired" name="Work Required" type="boolean"></activiti:formProperty>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-53297083-66C8-4FB3-A5BF-0672E68D0FA7" sourceRef="start-progress" targetRef="initiate-review"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-34C91FDF-757A-4676-A42C-E4FDC4F3549A" sourceRef="initiate-review" targetRef="sid-2E9F7CFB-5DAE-425D-9B86-7DE000E66627"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="sid-040D6C5C-BA05-44B4-98BF-AB2672C4ABE3"></endEvent>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_test-issue-workflow">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="test-flow" id="BPMNPlane_test-flow">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-5A259606-C7C4-4A8E-95F0-F2E8B9D0301E" id="BPMNShape_sid-5A259606-C7C4-4A8E-95F0-F2E8B9D0301E">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="105.0" y="130.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="start-progress" id="BPMNShape_start-progress">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="270.0" y="105.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="initiate-review" id="BPMNShape_initiate-review">
</definitions>
```

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The new Activiti 6 UI uses a different way do display forms. It includes a Form Designer that enables designing forms by dragging and dropping fields. Forms are then referenced using the activiti:formKey attribute in start events and user tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Bassam's answer.
Form Properties are no longer used in the Activiti 6 UI, they are in place for use with custom UI's and backward compatibility.
Thanks,
Greg

Comment: So... how I can use rest to get formProperties? When I use form/form-data?{taskId}, I can't get the form I designed in UI.